# How does R make the .pkg file for installation on Mac OS X?

Tags: r

CRAN allows Mac users to install R with a `.pkg` file for download here:

https://cran.r-project.org/bin/macosx/

Presumably this is generated by running pkgbuild on a compiled version of R.  Does anyone know where the source script for this process is located? Or how the process could be pseudo-replicated?

Comment: This seems less an `[r]` question and much, much more a MacOS question. (I think you are confused by the shared name of two distinct types of "package" files.) The `.pkg` format is something that `Xcode.app` produces and then is passed to the Mac `Installer.app`. It's _not_ under the control of R.

Comment: Someone on the R team (I think Simon Urbanek) has the code that goes into the .pkg file and composes the scripts for it.  I am hoping to find that source code.  The `.pkg` file format is controlled by Mac, but the process that makes it and the `postflight` scripts it contains, etc. is controlled by the R team.

Comment: There are very few of the R-Core who frequent SO. Simon Urbanek happens to be one of those who have been seen from time to time, but I've not seen any postings from him recently. There are several R mailing lists, but referring people to them seems to generate annoyance on the part of SO. Nevertheless, if you do decide to go that route, I would suggest carefully reading the Listinfo page and the Rhelp Posting Guide before you craft your letter to R-SIG-Mac.

Comment: Thanks, I sent a ping to the list! Sadly, no dice on the source code, but a few kind people chimed in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source for the commands that make the R bundle is not available.  However, you can download the produced bundle, and use the OS X pkg utilities (`pkgbuild`, `pkgutil`, `productbuild`) to modify it to include other things you might need.  For example, the script below downloads the distributed bundle, adds any packages in the users R library to it, then rebundles it for distribution.

```
wget https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/macosx/R-3.5.0.pkg    

BUILD_DIR=build
mkdir $BUILD_DIR    

# Unpack the CRAN R distribution 
pkgutil --expand R-3.5.0.pkg $BUILD_DIR/tmp_pkg    


# Now to add more default packages to the R package payload
# First extract the payload
pushd $BUILD_DIR/tmp_pkg/r.pkg/
cat Payload | gzip -d | cpio -id    

# Copy all of the users R packages into this
# folder for distribution
R_LIB_DIR=$(sed -e 's/\[1\] \"//' -e 's/\"//' <<< $(RScript -e '.libPaths()'))
R_PAYLOAD_DIR="R.framework/Resources/library"
for dirname in $R_LIB_DIR/*
do
    pkg_name=$(basename $dirname)
    if [ ! -d $R_PAYLOAD_DIR/$pkg_name ]
    then
        echo "Moving package:" $pkg_name
        cp -r $dirname $R_PAYLOAD_DIR/$pkg_name
    fi
done    

# Let's remove the debug symbols and their associated plists for compiled code in R
# packages, as they bloat the installation
find $R_PAYLOAD_DIR -name '*so.dSYM' -prune -exec rm -rf {} \;    

# Now build a new r.pkg
pkgbuild --component R.framework --scripts Scripts/ \
   --identifier org.r-project.R.el-capitan.fw.pkg \
   --version 30574626 \ # You may want to change this
   --install-location /Library/Frameworks \
   ../../r.pkg    

popd    

# Remove original one we've replaced
rm -rf $BUILD_DIR/tmp_pkg/r.pkg    

# Flatten remaining components distributed with R
# (necessary to repackage it all).
for fname in $BUILD_DIR/tmp_pkg/*.pkg
do
    bname=$(basename $fname)
    pkgutil --flatten $fname $BUILD_DIR/$bname 
done    

mv $BUILD_DIR/tmp_pkg/Resources $BUILD_DIR/
mv $BUILD_DIR/tmp_pkg/Distribution $BUILD_DIR/    

(cd $BUILD_DIR; productbuild --distribution Distribution --resources Resources ../R-With-Your-Stuff.pkg)
```